# Facing Issue while using Spark-BigQuery-Connector with Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

I am able to read the data from BigQuery table via spark big query connector from local, but when I deploy this in Google Cloud and running via dataproc, I am getting below exception.If you see the below logs, its able to identify the schema of the table and after that it waited for 8-10 mins and threw the below exception. Can someone help on this?

```
20/10/30 13:15:40 INFO org.spark_project.jetty.util.log: Logging initialized @2859ms
20/10/30 13:15:40 INFO org.spark_project.jetty.server.Server: jetty-9.3.z-SNAPSHOT, build timestamp: unknown, git hash: unknown
20/10/30 13:15:40 INFO org.spark_project.jetty.server.Server: Started @2959ms
20/10/30 13:15:40 INFO org.spark_project.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: Started ServerConnector
20/10/30 13:15:40 WARN org.apache.spark.scheduler.FairSchedulableBuilder: Fair Scheduler configuration file not found so jobs will be scheduled in FIFO order. To use fair scheduling, configure pools in fairscheduler.xml or set spark.scheduler.allocation.file to a file that contains the configuration.
20/10/30 13:15:41 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at <REMOVED_RM_INFO_FOR_SECURITY_PURPOSE>
20/10/30 13:15:41 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.AHSProxy: Connecting to Application History server at <REMOVED_HISTORY_SERVER_INFO_FOR_SECURITY_PURPOSE>
20/10/30 13:15:44 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1603913904708_0011
20/10/30 13:15:50 INFO com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryUtilScala: BigQuery client project id is [<REMOVED_PROJECT_ID_FOR_SECURITY_PURPOSE>}], derived from the parentProject option
20/10/30 13:15:52 INFO com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.direct.DirectBigQueryRelation: Querying table <REMOVED_TABLE_NAME_FOR_SECURITY_PURPOSE>, parameters sent from Spark: requiredColumns=[country,ssn,fname,postal_code,lname,city,tenant_id,mob,PARTY_ID,src_id], filters=[]
20/10/30 13:15:52 INFO com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.direct.DirectBigQueryRelation: Going to read from <REMOVED_TABLE_NAME_FOR_SECURITY_PURPOSE> columns=[country, ssn, fname, postal_code, lname, city, tenant_id, mob, PARTY_ID, src_id], filter=''
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnavailableException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:69)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:97)
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:68)
    at shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1074)
    at shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:30)
    at shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1213)
    at shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:983)
    at shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:771)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:545)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:515)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:426)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$500(ClientCallImpl.java:66)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:689)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$900(ClientCallImpl.java:577)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:751)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:740)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Suppressed: com.google.api.gax.rpc.AsyncTaskException: Asynchronous task failed
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptions.callAndTranslateApiException(ApiExceptions.java:57)
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable.call(UnaryCallable.java:112)
        at com.google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1.BigQueryReadClient.createReadSession(BigQueryReadClient.java:230)
        at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.direct.DirectBigQueryRelation.buildScan(DirectBigQueryRelation.scala:134)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$10.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:293)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$10.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:293)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$pruneFilterProject$1.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:338)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$pruneFilterProject$1.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:337)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy.pruneFilterProjectRaw(DataSourceStrategy.scala:415)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy.pruneFilterProject(DataSourceStrategy.scala:333)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:289)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:63)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:439)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:67)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3260)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2495)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2709)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:254)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:731)
        at com.gcp.poc.SparkBigQueryConnector.main(SparkBigQueryConnector.java:33)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:890)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:217)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:137)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:533)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedNoRouteToHostException: null: bigquerystorage.googleapis.com
    at io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.throwConnectException(Errors.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.unix.Socket.connect(Socket.java:255)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel.doConnect0(AbstractEpollChannel.java:758)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel.doConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:743)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.connect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:585)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.connect(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1291)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:545)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:530)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.connect(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:50)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:545)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:530)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.connect(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:50)
    at io.grpc.netty.WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler.connect(WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler.java:150)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:545)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$1000(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:38)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$11.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:535)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:309)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException
    ... 22 more
20/10/30 13:25:35 INFO org.spark_project.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: Stopped Spark
Job output is complete
```

Pom.xml:

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <spark.version>2.3.4</spark.version>
        <scala.version>2.11.8</scala.version>
    </properties>

    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-nexus-staging</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-shared-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>0.13.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-bigquery</artifactId>
            <version>1.116.10</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>failureaccess</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>listenablefuture</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-bigquery_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>0.17.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>failureaccess</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>listenablefuture</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.10</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>30.0-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Maven Shade Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
                            <relocations>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>com.google.common</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>shaded.com.google.common</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>com.google.protobuf</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>shaded.com.google.protobuf</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                            </relocations>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <destFile>target/ut-coverage.exec</destFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <dataFile>target/ut-coverage.exec</dataFile>
                            <outputDirectory>target/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Sample Code:

```
public static SparkSession getSparkSession() {
        return SparkSession.builder()
                //.master("local[*]")
                .config("spark.jars","gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest.jar")
                .getOrCreate();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkSession session = getSparkSession();
        Dataset<Row> readDS = session.read().format("bigquery")
                .option("table", "<PROJECT_ID.DATASET.TABLENAME>")
                .option("project", projectId)
                .option("parentProject", projectId)
                .load();
        readDS.show(1,false);
    }
```

Comment: I have a feeling it's a combination of few things:

* Can you please verify you can ping `bigquerystorage.googleapis.com` from the cluster?
* You include the spark BigQuery connector in your POM and in your shaded jar, but then you also import it externally in the code (using the `spark.jar` config). Please choose one of them.
* Just to be sure, are you using Dataproc image 1.3?
* You can set the scope of the spark and scala dependencies to provided, it should reduce the size of your jar and will make sure you use the code provided by the installation

Comment: @DavidRabinowitz I am able to ping on bigquerystorage.googleapis.com from the cluster. And I tried keeping the scope as provided for both the spark and scala dependency and removing the spark.jars from code but still facing same issue. Yes I'm using Dataproc image 1.3.75-debian10

Comment: @DavidRabinowitz We upgraded the dataproc version to 1.5.21-debian10 and on the other hand upgraded the spark version to  2.4.7 and scala to 2.4.7 but now I am getting different issue.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:334)
 at org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.message.MessageSerializer.readMessage(MessageSerializer.java:543)

Comment: I gave an answer on the second question

Comment: Thanks @DavidRabinowitz. Its working now :)

Comment: Thanks @DavidRabinowitz It's working now. Curious to know what is the difference between both the dependencies?

Comment: It contains all the dependencies internally (shaded), so there's no dependency collusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For other's,

Here is the big-query dependency I used and its working fine now.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>0.17.3</version>
    <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>failureaccess</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>listenablefuture</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```